# OnPropertyChange causes Deadlock on Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, deadlock, freezed

in my Xamarin.Forms application I have an ObservableCollection to present different Views in a ContentPresenter. It is kind of interview when the user pushes a new view with new controls by pressing a button to answer some questions.

That's my collection:

`private ObservableCollection<View> AbfrageContentViews { get; set; }`

and a `public View CurrentView {get; set; }` field to hold the current view (Grid).

In XAML there is a `<ContentView Content="{Binding CurrentView}/>`

**First:**
In my UWP Solution everything is working fine! When it comes to Android following situation occurs:

My ViewModel seeds many Grids to the collection and when the users taps the 'next' Button, following Code executes:

```
private async Task ExecuteNextView()
         {
                if (AbfrageContentViews == null || AbfrageContentViews.Count() < 1) return;
                var currentListPosition = AbfrageContentViews.IndexOf(CurrentView);

                currentListPosition++;
                if (currentListPosition < AbfrageContentViews.Count())
                {
                    
                    var griditem = (Grid)CurrentView;
                                        
                    var oldView = griditem;

                    var newView = (Grid)AbfrageContentViews[currentListPosition];
                    newView.Opacity = 0;
                    
                    await oldView.FadeTo(0, 190, Easing.SpringOut);
                    
                    CurrentView = AbfrageContentViews[currentListPosition];´

                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentView));

                    await newView.FadeTo(1, 190, Easing.SpringIn);

                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Progress));

                }
}
```

On `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentView));` the screen freezes. My breakpoints while debugging also continue.

**What I did:**
To invoke the Task in MainThread I tried different ways to accomplish:

1. `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await ExecuteNextView());` directly from `Command`
2. `await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () => await ExecuteNextView());` directly from `Command`
3. `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentView));`
4. `await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync` & `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` in my `ExecuteNextView` Task/Method.

Nothing works like it does on UWP (see the workflow in the GIF):
[image: Workflow UWP]

Thank you for your guidance.

Marco

Comment: What does the `My breakpoints while debugging also continue` mean? The code could contine when you debug?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. When I debug single steps (F11) and pass `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentView));` the debugger continues the execution and doesn't stop anymore.

Comment: It seems you implement INotifyPropertyChanged. As i know, we normally use the `OnPropertyChanged` for the property name. Do i miss something?

Comment: Yes, in my BaseViewModel there's following implementation:

`public void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }`

`public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`


Once again: It works on UWP. I Something is missing on Android I guess some Threadsafety-problems...I don't know

Comment: I could not reproduce. Could you provide a code snippet for me to reproduce?